# Dynamic sql cursor

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, dynamic-sql

I am getting "Incorrect syntax near '.' " when i run the following query.

```
DECLARE 
@StaffID INT = 4,
@Cursorsql nvarchar(4000);  

SET @Cursorsql = 'DECLARE curStaff CURSOR FOR ';
SET @Cursorsql = @Cursorsql + ' SELECT s.StaffID, o.OfficeName, s.FirstName '; 
SET @Cursorsql = @Cursorsql + ' ' + 's.LastName FROM Staff s  '; 
SET @Cursorsql = @Cursorsql + ' INNER JOIN Offices o ON o.OfficeID = s.OfficeID '; 
SET @Cursorsql = @Cursorsql + ' WHERE (s.OfficeID = @OfficeID OR @OfficeID = 0) '; 
IF @StaffID > 0 
 SET @Cursorsql = @Cursorsql + ' AND s.StaffID = @StaffID '; 
SET @Cursorsql = @Cursorsql + ' ORDER BY s.OfficeID, s.FirstName, s.LastName ';  

exec (@Cursorsql);
```

Comment: Not related but you can't use `exec (@CursorSql)` with parameters. You need to use `sp_executesql @CursorSql, N'@StaffID int', @StaffID`

Comment: You're doing dynamic SQL, but still making a parameter "optional" (`OR @OfficeID = 0`)?  Note that SQL Server doesn't like this type of query (not properly optimized).  You'd be better off just dropping/adding the condition as necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed a Comma after `s.FirstName`:

```
DECLARE 
@StaffID INT = 4,
@Cursorsql nvarchar(4000);  

SET @Cursorsql = 'DECLARE curStaff CURSOR FOR ';
SET @Cursorsql = @Cursorsql + ' SELECT s.StaffID, o.OfficeName, s.FirstName, '; 
SET @Cursorsql = @Cursorsql + ' ' + 's.LastName FROM Staff s  '; 
SET @Cursorsql = @Cursorsql + ' INNER JOIN Offices o ON o.OfficeID = s.OfficeID '; 
SET @Cursorsql = @Cursorsql + ' WHERE (s.OfficeID = @OfficeID OR @OfficeID = 0) '; 
IF @StaffID > 0 
 SET @Cursorsql = @Cursorsql + ' AND s.StaffID = @StaffID '; 
SET @Cursorsql = @Cursorsql + ' ORDER BY s.OfficeID, s.FirstName, s.LastName ';  

exec (@Cursorsql);
```

Answer (score 0):

Printing out the dynamic sql and checking for syntax errors is always a good idea and easy way to troubleshoot. You are missing a comma between `s.FirstName` and `s.LastName` in the `SELECT` list

Try this -

```
DECLARE 
@StaffID INT = 4,
@Cursorsql nvarchar(4000);  

SET @Cursorsql = 'DECLARE curStaff CURSOR FOR ';
SET @Cursorsql = @Cursorsql + ' SELECT s.StaffID, o.OfficeName, s.FirstName, '; 
SET @Cursorsql = @Cursorsql + ' s.LastName FROM Staff s  '; 
SET @Cursorsql = @Cursorsql + ' INNER JOIN Offices o ON o.OfficeID = s.OfficeID '; 
SET @Cursorsql = @Cursorsql + ' WHERE (s.OfficeID = @OfficeID OR @OfficeID = 0) '; 
IF @StaffID > 0 
 SET @Cursorsql = @Cursorsql + ' AND s.StaffID = @StaffID '; 
SET @Cursorsql = @Cursorsql + ' ORDER BY s.OfficeID, s.FirstName, s.LastName ';  
sp_executesql @CursorSql, N'@StaffID int', @StaffID;
```